# Sybase Query with Java Prepared Statements Not Working

Tags: java, sybase, prepared-statement

I have a web application using Java/JSP that was running off a MySQL database which I've now moved to Sybase.

I've changed what I believe are all the relevant connection parts (Sybase Connector and relevant code)

I've been using PreparedStatements for my queries. What was working in MySQL is now no longer returning anything (errors or results).

The first simple query I've been testing is a login form which should be matching the user values for name and password in the table "appuser".

The Prepared Statement in the code provided used to work but no longer does with Sybase.

Relevant code is below. Let me know if anything else is needed.

```
public void connectDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
{
    /* String userName="****";
    String password="******";
    String url="jdbc:sybase:sybdev1dw/ETL_MON";
    Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver").newInstance();
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password); */

    String driver = "com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver";
    String host = "********";
    String dbName = "********";
    String url = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:" + host  + ":4110" +"?SERVICENAME=" + dbName;
    String username = "*******";
    String password = "*********";

    Class.forName(driver);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    System.out.println("Connection successful"+conn);

}

public Boolean loginAction(String name, String pass, String role,HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {
    Boolean valid=false;
    session=request.getSession();
    PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT pass FROM appuser WHERE name=?");
    stmt.setString(1, name);
    results=stmt.executeQuery();

    System.out.println("loginAction:"+results.getFetchSize());

    while(results.next())
    {
        if(results.getString("pass").equals(pass)) 
        {
            valid=true;
            session.setAttribute("name",name);
            session.setAttribute("role",role);
        }
        else
        {
            valid=false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("loginAction:"+valid);

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: No error seems to occur. It acts as though it ran the query and no results were returned, then later in my code redirects to the "Your login failed" screen.

Comment: Do your system.out.println statements actually print ? What does it mean when you say "not working" ?

Comment: Yes, the Println statements return:
Connection successfulcom.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection@a36b53
loginAction:0
loginAction:false

Comment: It's printing to the console that valid=false

Comment: (sorry, deleted my question after i saw you posted a comment that answered it) Are you specifying a schema in the url? (otherwise maybe it can't find appuser?)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you please clarify?

Comment: "appuser" is the name of the table in the database.

Comment: A schema is a construct for grouping tables together. Since your query isn't returning anything i'm trying to think of why it would fail, wondering if how you're referring to the table doesn't suit Sybase somehow.

Comment: I'm stuck because I believe it's connected to the database properly (seems to create the Sybase connection), the query looks okay, and it's not throwing any exceptions as far as I can tell.

Comment: Is your password encrypted ? Looks like everything is working fine except that your string compare between the database returned password and your password parameter fails

Comment: I just added another println:
System.out.println(results.getString("pass"));

After the query is run, and it returns the correct password, so the query works.

Comment: For now the password is not encrypted, so there does seem to be something wrong with the comparison like you said.

Comment: printing results.getFetchSize() is not useful, it doesn't say how many rows are returned. try adding a line to stdout immediately after each line where you set valid (*BOTH* to true or false). I'm not convinced you get only 1 row back.

Comment: Does your select statement return more than one row?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. If it did, it would print out the SOP I just added more than once. I added the printlns after the valid=boolean lines and it returns false. I also added a println(pass) in the while loop before the if statement to see if pass and results.getString("pass") were the same, and they are. But the comparison still fails and I can't see why.

Comment: Try using a trim .. result.getString("pass").trim().equals(pass.trim())

Comment: ...That worked! Go figure. Any reason why it worked before under MySQL but didn't now? I hadn't changed that code when switching DBs.

Comment: If you add that as an official answer, I can give you the checkmark.

Comment: Its possible that the column definition is Sybase was such that it was padding spaces .. Not very familiar with Sybase ..but we have this problem in Oracle .. where if you define a char() field, it will pad spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String compare is failing possibly because of spaces being padded to the database column.

```
result.getString("pass").trim().equals(pass.trim())
```

One other suggestion. Instead of doing a `while(results.next())` , do an `if(results.next())` if you are confident it will always return exactly one row ( or zero ).